# Cannot install Openvino with pip

Tags: python, pip, openvino

I'm trying to install Openvino to convert a Keras model into a representation for the inference engine. I'm running the command:

```
python3 openvino/tools/mo/mo_tf.py —model_13.h5/ --input_shape=\[180,180\]
```

This returns the error:

```
from openvino.tools.mo.subprocess_main import subprocess_main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openvino'
```

I've tried `pip install openvino` but consistently get:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openvino (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for openvino
```

To try and make sure the versions of python for running the script and installing Openvino are the same, I've tried:

```
python3 -m pip install openvino
```

The content of the mo_tf.py script is simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Copyright (C) 2018-2021 Intel Corporation
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from openvino.tools.mo.subprocess_main import subprocess_main
    subprocess_main(framework='tf')
```

Has anyone seen this issue and found a workaround?

Comment: Is the `python3` you're using to run the script the exact same one that you used to `pip install openvino`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried specifying with python3 -m pip install openvino

Comment: When you try pip install openvino, does it actually say successfully installed or requirement already satisfied?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The latest version of openvino is 2021.4.2. [The list of packages to download](https://pypi.org/project/openvino/2021.4.2/#files) by `pip` includes packages for Python 3.6-3.9 for Linux, MacOS on Intel, and Windows; only packages for 64-bit platforms are provided. No packages for Python 3.10 and no source code.

The solution is either to [compile from sources](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/wiki/BuildingCode), or [install with Docker or install from Anaconda](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_images.html). Or downgrade to Python 3.9.

Comment: Yes, compatibility issues gives error like this, `no module found`, as some packages depends on specific version of python.

Comment: Supported Python version for OpenVINO on Linux, MacOS, and Windows 10 is Python 3.6-3.8.


You may build the OpenVINO master branch from source. Steps to build OpenVINO from source on Linux is available at the following link:
https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/wiki/BuildingForLinux

Comment: After that you can convert your .H5 model to IR according to the steps in the following page:
https://docs.openvino.ai/2021.4/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Convert_Model_From_TensorFlow.html#keras-h5

Answer (score 4):

On a separate note, if you happen to install `openvino-dev` instead of `openvino` consider adding quote escape as by default zsh (not bash) interprets square brackets as an expression for pattern matching.

To resolve this issue, you need to escape the command with quotes:

Use this

`pip install 'openvino-dev[tensorflow2,mxnet,caffe]'`

Instead of

`pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2,mxnet,caffe]`

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is using Mac-M1, This command will solve this issue.

```
pip install openvino-arm
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a version conflict. Install your required version in a virtual environment