# Cannot install Tensorflow 2.4.1 as a dependency for OpenVino

Tags: tensorflow, pip, openvino

When going through the process of installing OpenVino as documented [here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_macos.html), I'm running:

```
sudo ./install_prerequisites.sh
```

and getting

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow~=2.4.1 (from versions: 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.8.0rc0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow~=2.4.1
```

As suggested in the documentation, you can configure frameworks individually if there are errors. However, even using `pip` it doesn't seem there is a matching distribution for Tensorflow 2.4.1:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.4.1
```

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.4.1
```

How can you get Tensorflow 2.4.1 installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70501550/7976758) you how to debug such problems. Well, let's see.

The list of available packages for [tensorflow 2.4.1](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.4.1/#files) includes wheels for Python 3.6-3.8. No 3.9 and no source code. Wheels for Python 3.9 are available starting from [tensorflow 2.5.0rc0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.5.0rc0/#files) — exactly like is said in the error message.

What can you do? 1) Downgrade once more, to Python 3.8. Or 2) Use more recent OpenVino source code; the current sources at GitHub [list](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/blob/b144089ef7da6383ff61835df11ba34c7b04c69b/tools/mo/requirements_tf.txt) `tensorflow~=2.5` as a dependency. Or 3) Find in your downloaded sources files `requirements*.txt` and replace version `tensorflow~=2.4.1` with `2.5.0`.

Comment: Refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements, 
Python 3.9 support requires TensorFlow 2.5 or later.