# No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.4.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I get an error install tensorflow==2.4.1

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.4.1 tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1 --upgrade
```

This is the error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.4.1 (from versions: 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0)
```

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.4.1

Comment: What is the version of python that you use? If it's `python 3.9` then `tensorflow` is only [compatible](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) starting `2.5`. Looked up in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70526218/3868453) answer.

Comment: Hi @Eben_Success, as per the tested build configurations, `Tensorflow 2.4` is compatible with `python 3.6 - 3.8`. Kindly share additional details in question like platform, python version etc., for better assistance and please refer to this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) to check the compatibility. Thank you!