# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openvino.inference_engine' while installing openvino on WSL2

Tags: python, ubuntu-22.04, openvino

I am working on Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL2.

I tried following the steps [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/blob/2024.0.0/docs/dev/build_linux.md) to install openvino runtime but it still doesn't work.

I also tried following the steps [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html?VERSION=v_2024_0_0&OP_SYSTEM=LINUX&DISTRIBUTION=APT) with the apt distribution for ubuntu and it also hasn't worked.

Error message:

> from openvino.inference_engine import IECore ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openvino.inference_engine'

Comment: Could be related: [Cannot install Openvino with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70501334/21350362)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from OpenVINO™ toolkit 2024, [OpenVINO™ C++/C/Python 1.0 APIs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/release-notes/openvino/2024-0.html#:%7E:text=OpenVINO%20C%2B%2B/C/Python%201.0%20APIs) have been deprecated. Please refer to [OpenVINO™ API 2.0 Transition Guide](https://docs.openvino.ai/2023.3/openvino_2_0_transition_guide.html#openvino-api-2-0-transition-guide) to migrate Inference Engine-based applications to OpenVINO™ API 2.0.